# How does "less" switch to the text, then back to the prompt?

Tags: command-line, git, less

When I run `less` on some file, the prompt goes away, and I get the contents of the file on screen. Then when I press <kbd>q</kbd>, it goes back to the prompt. I think `less` does this by saving the current terminal buffer, opening a new buffer, outputting the file into the new one, then when closed, discarding the new buffer, and restoring the old, but I don't know what this process is called or how it does this.

I looked in `man less` but didn't find anything. I tried googling it, but couldn't find anything useful, except that the `screen` command can do the same thing with shell sessions.

Ultimately, I'm asking because I want `git diff` to use a new buffer instead of printing inline. I've already set `GIT_PAGER=less` and `git --paginate diff`, but they didn't change anything. And I have a workaround, but it's a bit long: `git diff --color=always | less -R`

Update: After some research, it looks like `tput smcup` and `tput rmcup` are high-level commands to do the same thing, probably using the `termcap` package.

Comment: Keyword: “termcap initialization and deinitialization strings”, see `less`'s `-X` option which disables this behaviour. Btw `man less` helps: “Less  uses  termcap  (or terminfo  on some systems), so it can run on a variety of terminals.”

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console#man

Comment: Related: [How does terminal programs add scrolling to the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22537797/4518341)

Comment: What are your `less` settings? (Look at the `LESS` variable in particular.) On my system, `git` pages by default, using `less`; but if you have `-X`, `-E` or `-F` in your `less` configuration it could give the impression that it’s not initialising the terminal at all.

Comment: @StephenKitt `$LESS` is unset. To clarify, `git` uses `less` on my system, but doesn't initialize a new terminal. I've tried setting git's pager as `less -+X` in the gitconfig and `$GIT_PAGER`, but neither worked.

Comment: What’s your `TERM` set to?

Comment: @StephenKitt xterm

Comment: Disregard my comment about the pager. I don't think I set it correctly (didn't export the var, forgot to save the gitconfig).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of `less`’s screen management functions are in its [`screen.c`](https://sources.debian.org/src/less/487-0.1/screen.c/) module. At startup, unless it’s in “no init” (`-X` or `--no-init`) mode, it outputs its `sc_init` string, [which is `termcap`’s `ti` string](https://sources.debian.org/src/less/487-0.1/screen.c/#L1212) ([“terminal initialisation”](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html#SEC39), which gets the terminal ready for full-screen, cursor-controlling operation). At exit, it outputs its `sc_deinit` string, [which is `termcap`’s `te` string](https://sources.debian.org/src/less/487-0.1/screen.c/#L1216).

The behaviour you’re seeing is the default behaviour with `git`, if `less` isn’t configured (*i.e.* the `LESS` variable is unset); when that’s the case, `git` runs `less` with the `FRX` options, which cause `less` to respectively quit if the content fits on a single screen, display colours, and skip initialising the terminal.

To get the behaviour you’re after, set `LESS` to `-R`, or set the `core.pager` `git` setting to something like `less -+X` (see `man git-config` for details).

Comment: Setting `LESS=-R` worked, but setting `core.pager` as `less -R` didn't. However setting `core.pager` as `less -+X` did.

Comment: You’re welcome! `less -+X` is the recommended setting in `man git-config`, which is why I mentioned the latter, but I’ve added it explicitly to the answer.